# RHEL 6.3 (64 bits) : Install a package to a specific version of php

Tags: linux, yum, rhel

I actually have RHEL installed (which has a native php). I'm trying to `yum install php-pdo_mysql` but it goes in conflict with the native php (5.3) but i'm trying to install it on the 5.4.4 version.

When I do `find / -name php.ini` I get 2 results :

`/etc/php.ini` (5.3.3)

`/data/php/param/php.ini` (5.4.4)

it seems that when I try to install php-pdo_mysql it tries to install on the 5.3.3 instead of the 5.4.4.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `yum` will install package to the system directories, such as `/usr/bin/`, `/etc`, and so on; and it will only check these packages installed through `yum` or `rpm` for possible conflicts and dependences.

Your `/data/php/param/php.ini` looks like from a local building of PHP, therefore you cannot use `yum` to install `php-pdo_mysql` for it. You probably need to build a local copy of `php-pdo_mysql` for your php in `/data/php`.